# Hbase shell remote commands

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, hbase, remote-access

How can I run this command in a remote shell ?

```
ssh namenode1 "su - hbase -c 'echo "create_namespace 'toto'" | hbase shell -n'"
```

This doesn't work :

```
ERROR NameError: undefined local variable or method `toto' for #<Object:0x1d4f5506>
```

Thanks

Comment: @jww this is about how to escape strings in bash language.

Comment: @Robert - Ack. What does "how does Bash work" and "how do I run a remote command" have to do with programming or development? Until its directly programming or development related, its off-topic here. There are sites in the Stack Exchange network that handle questions about running arbitrary commands.

Comment: @jww Well, the idea is to put it in a script later, but you're right it's maybe more about Linux stuff than programming.

Comment: @skr By the way I used \ to replace ' but it doesn't work, could you please be more specific about what to change in my command. Thanks

Comment: It works like this on local server : su - hbase -c "echo 'create_namespace '\'"toto'\'"' | hbase shell -n", but when I include it in a ssh namenode01 "my cmd" it doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it, here the answer :

ssh namenode01 "su - hbase -c \"echo 'create_namespace '\'"toto2'\'"' | hbase shell -n\""

Thanks for your help!